# Azure API Management access specific values from a defined variable

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-api-management, azure-api-apps

I'm using the Azure API management, and I have the following response stored in this variable

```
<set-variable name="externalAPIResponse" value="@((IResponse)context.Variables["response"])" />
```

The response, has the following structure :

```
 "value": {
    "status": {
        "code": 400,
        "reason": "Bad Request"
    },
...
}
```

I'm struggling to access the status code from this variable, in order to take further decisions based on the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@{
  var response = JObject.Parse((IResponse)context.Variables["response"]);
  string code = response?['value']?['status']?['code'];

  return code;


}
```